# How to override a padding in only one layout via Java in Android

Tags: java, android

I'm creating an android application with Navigation Drawer, and I don't want to resign from default dimens vaules which are:

```
<dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
<dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>
```

I want to remove this value only in one layout - with Map Fragment. 
How can I do this?

So far I tried this, but it doesn't remove it, only can increase them.

```
   @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_school, container, false);
        view.setPadding(0,0,0,650);

        return view;
    }
```

[image: screenshot]

Greetings

////edit
Here's my fragment's xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.test.SchoolFragment">

        <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            tools:context="com.example.mapwithmarker.MapsMarkerActivity" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: view.setPadding(-16,-16,-16,650);

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work with negative values.

Answer (score 0):

The padding/margin here are set to your activity, while you are modifying the padding of your fragment's root view. In this case the padding/margin set in activity will remain the same i.e `16dp`. Try removing padding/margin of activity's root view.

Comment: How should I do it properly?

Comment: In your layout xml file of Activity, remove attributes related to padding/margin. i.e `android:paddingBottom`, `android:paddingTop`, `android:layout_marginBottom`, `android:layout_marginTop` etc.